# Jmeter cookie manager not passing cookies

Tags: jmeter

I would like to start by saying that I have gone through several answers on related topics here and none seems to fix my issue.

I have created a new thread group and added a new header manager and cookie manager to it. I have 3 https requests in the thread group. The first call is an authentication call which needs no cookies. This call returns 3 cookies in response headers that I need to pass for further requests.

Authentication call is working fine. But the calls after authentication is not working since the cookies are not set. I have added 'CookieManager.check.cookies=false' to the user.properties file and still seeing '[no cookies]' in all requests. I have also tried adding a dummy cookie to the cookie manager under 'User-Defined Cookies' section as shown in the screenshot and even that cookie is not added to the requests.I am getting '[no cookies]' in all requests.

[image: jmeter screenshot]

I have also tried all options under policy manager like standard, compatible etc without any success. Also tried this in Jmeter 3.1 and 3.3 (latest version) and the same issue observed.

Any suggestions or solutions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Are both requests in same domain and path?

Comment: Same domain, different path.

Answer (score 1):

1. To add a custom cookie you **must** set its `Domain` to your application domain, otherwise it will not be picked up
2. Your `Path` should start with a forward slash `/` and need to match the request URL path , however it is better to remove anything from that input
3. It might be the case you're suffering from [Bug 56358](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56358) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 3.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-3.3), it can resolve your issue
4. As a last resort you can always fetch cookies you need from the [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

Comment: 1. This makes sense. I took a look at the cookies and looks like the reponse cookie JSESSIONID from my authentication call doesn't have a 'Domain' value attached to it. I have tried to set this as a user defined cookie in the cookie manager and the pass the same domain as the other 2 cookies. However this doesn't seems to work. Request still failing.  Tried 2, 3 & 4  steps without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try going the dirty way and get the cookies values from the previous response and use them in the following parameters or store it. You can do this using a Post processor - Regular Expression Extractor that you put in the first Authentication request. Here is a site that explains how to use RegEx https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/09/07/jmeter-regular-expression-extractor/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried this already by adding them to the headers like 'Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=value' but that didnt work either. I am familiar with regex extraction.